# Window control mnemonics in gnome shell ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-shell

I have switched to gnome shell in my ubuntu 16.04. I often use ALT + Space and then 'c' to close, 'n' to minimize the window. But, I haven't found them in gnome shell. As shown in the first picture, there is no mnemonics highlighted [image: There is no mnemonics highlighted].

[image: Also, Switching to other window of same application wasn't showed under it...]Also, Switching to other window of same application wasn't showed under it...  I can only see Quit... Ref Image2

Comment: Although [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032810/how-to-use-window-menu-accelerators-mnemonics-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts) OP uses 18.04, I believe the issue is identical.