# How to use window menu accelerators/mnemonics in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, accessibility

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I have used simple keyboard shortcut to set property *Always on Top* (Nautilus window as example):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>,

   [image: Alt+Space to show window menu]
2. <kbd>t</kbd>
3. After next <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or right mouse click I see that window was set to *Always on Top*.

   [image: window is set to Always on Top]

In standard Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME Shell I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

[image: window menu on Alt+Space]

but it does not react to <kbd>t</kbd>.

Seems to be a real [bug 1710421 since 17.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1710421).

---

How to enable such menu accelerators/mnemonics in standard Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: 4 yr. old gnome-shell bug, not going to be fix, you're wasting your time. Use any other shell and it works fine..

Comment: I'm using window manager right now so I can't really test it. But the second answer in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126233/how-to-set-a-shortcut-for-always-on-top-for-window), the one using wmctrl, I think it's worth a try. Not a direct answer to your question but you can use your keyboard at least.

Comment: One of the few questions where the question has more upvotes than the answer!  **:D :D :D**  Good question!

Comment: why would they remove something that users are so accustomed to?

Comment: @N0rbert I'm a fan of XFCE and I've always liked it and used it. It's only the Ubuntu 16 to 18 upgrade that changed this behavior. is XFCE also using Gnome shell under the hood?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84434/discussion-between-asgs-and-n0rbert).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**On GNOME Shell it is impossible!** Welcome to the new brave world with unpredictable limits and problems!

To get these shortcuts on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS in place you can switch to:

- **Unity** - installable with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop`:

  [image: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity desktop]
- **GNOME FlashBack** - installable with `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`:

  [image: GNOME FlashBack on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]
- **MATE Desktop Environment** (my favorite, as it avoids GNOMEs Hell) - installable with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`:

  [image: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with MATE DE]
- **XFCE** (`xubuntu-desktop^`) does not have mnemonic for *Always on Top*, but usable and looks very nice:

  [image: xUbuntu 18.04 LTS]
- **Cinnamon** (`cinnamon-desktop-environment`) have all necessary mnemonics:

  [image: Cinnamon on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]
- **KDE** (`kubuntu-desktop^`) have mnemonics, they may be accessed from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (so called *Window Operations Menu*) - for example to keep window above others you need to click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> (for *M*ore Actions), <kbd>A</kbd> (for Keep *A*bove Others) and menu is rich:

  [image: Kubuntu 18.04 LTS]
- **Openbox** (`openbox`), **LXDE / LXQT / Lubuntu** (`lubuntu-desktop^`, `lxqt`) have mnemonics, they are accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

  [image: OpenBox, LXDE/Lubuntu/LXQT on 18.04 LTS]
- **Budgie** (`ubuntu-budgie-desktop^`) have mnemonics, they are accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

  [image: Ubuntu Budgie]

Comment: Per [inputs from N0rber](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84434/discussion-between-asgs-and-n0rbert), I managed to remove Gnome shell and switched to Xubuntu. I get Xfce's simplicity along with the [Keyboard Mnemonics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5PCK.png). It's a win-win! Thank you very much!

Comment: You could add LXDE/Openbox :)

Comment: @DKBose added LXDE/Openbox, thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: what does the `^` do at the end of the package name?

Comment: @törzsmókus `^` means *task* as in [`tasksel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/tasksel.8.html). Used to correctly and fully install the desktop meta-packages.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there is no mnemonic support anymore for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> window menu. There appears to be no intentions to bring it back. [The current bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/914) report is two years old. The [original issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733297) was filed back in 2014.

Still, keyboard shortcuts are available for the most common actions. These are quicker as they do not require you to see the menu and reduce the effort to a single keystroke.

- Minimize: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
- Maximize: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.
- Restore: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> toggles between maximize and restore.
- Move: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
- Resize: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.
- Close window: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

These key assignments can be changed in Settings - Keyboard.

For **Always on top**, no keyboard combination is defined by default, nor exposed through Settings - Keyboard. You still can define a key combination using dconf-editor, or a gsettings command. For example, to set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for toggling a window on top, issue the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings always-on-top "['<Super>t']"
```

Undo with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings always-on-top
```

Comment: I temporarily resorted to assigning <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me. I had to wrap with quotes for this to work."['<Super>t']"

Comment: @shan Indeed, quotes are needed. Thanks for remarking this: I will correct asap.

Comment: For resize, also `Super`+`down` seems to works.

Comment: @CyriacAntony thank you, I added it. I also added the "legacy" Alt+F10 (was already defined like this in Windows, I guess) to toggle between maximized and normal.

Answer (score 7):

The KISS (Keep It Simply Stupid) answer to that is to do a simple:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and then <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

not as good as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and then <kbd>i</kbd>, but still better than:

- lifting your hand from the keyboard,
- looking for the mouse,
- pointing,
- clicking
- moving your hand back to the keyboard...

#### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: As of today, I can open the window menu with Alt+Space and move up and down the menu with the arrow keys. But I cannot use Enter to actually select any of the menu options.

Comment: One more thing. The flippant "¯\_(ツ)_/¯" response is insulting. I recommend editing it out.

Comment: It's a shrug @eksortso : it means "It's not a perfect solution, just a workaround"

Comment: Whenever I've seen that thing, the context suggested it meant "I don't know and I don't care." A harsh sentiment for a Q&A site, though I now suppose that wasn't your intention. And when I read that along with KISS, which once meant "Keep It Simple, Stupid" as an ironic maxim to developers, I interpreted your comment as frustration with the user, and reacted with hostility. Although I did try to remain civil, I'm not sure if actually I went too far.

Comment: Kiss shouldn't be thought of as an "ironic maxim to developers" it should be thought of as words to live by under most, to all circumstances.

Comment: @tatsu **+1**  Thanks!   **:-)**

Comment: This is a pretty _bad_ solution.  Let's hope there were a real mnemonics support.

Comment: like @eksortso said, ENTER (or Space or whatever I tried) does not select the highlighted menu option

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are several shortcuts to do so.
I don't know what they are in earlier ubuntu. 
They are my windows behaviours. 
Windows / action / ubuntu 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>n</kbd>    minimize    <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>x</kbd>    maximize     <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>r</kbd>    unmaximize<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>c</kbd>   close    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>m</kbd>    move     <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>s</kbd>    resize     <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
There are more in

```
setting  >  device  >  keyboard
```

You can `define or redefine all these shortcuts` there. 
But I thought pressing three keys......It's your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The GNOME Shell extension [Menu Keyboard Shortcut](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1695/menu-keyboard-shortcut/) by Edward Jiang fixes my most used maximize/minimze mnemonic.

Comment: I'm back on ubuntu/unity but if ever have to deal with gnome again will use this.

Answer (score -1):

There is key two key combination exist in gnome to maximize, minimize and  move (right or left).

Hold the Windows Key and play with Up/Down/Right and Left arrow keys

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-maximize.html.en