# Set window close and maximise shortcuts in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcuts, customization

Is there any way I can set shortcuts of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd> to close and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> to maximize the window?

It was perfect in Ubuntu 16.04 but removed in 18.04.
Please suggest any way to get that shortcut back in Ubuntu 18.04.

I looking for shortcut in right click context menu on titlebar as per the screenshot.

[image: top bar context menu]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't found my solution with that question. If you think so will you please paste that lines here in comment?

Comment: I'm asking for shortcut for options of rightclick on window titlebar.

Comment: Did you try to change the relevant action shortcuts in the *Windows* sections of the shortcut manager? The action names should be *Close window* (or *Hide window* if that's what you mean) and *Maximize window*.

Comment: That one is different one, I'm asking for the right click options as  screen shot given in question.

Comment: Seems to be a real bug (see link and images in [my question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032810/66509)  ).