# Keyboard shortcuts in terminal in Ubuntu 16, 18 and 20

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I used to `alt-space x` to toggle a terminal window between maximize (fullscreen) and unmaximize. This was in Ubuntu 16. But in Ubuntu 18 and 20 this doesn't work anymore. Is there some settings/preferences I'm not aware of to enable this or some other keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @User24601 indeed duplicate question but with an outdated answer that will not help the user. Not your fault ;-) : I consider this a flaw in how this  site works.

Comment: I have answered this very question in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032810/how-to-use-window-menu-accelerators-mnemonics-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts but the accepted answer there suggests you ditch Gnome Shell altogether,

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on this [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073930/558158) as to that such hotkeys indeed are not implemented in Gnome, and what you can do instead (apart from switching to another desktop as suggested in the answer.

These window menu hotkeys are quite universal, and a lot of people are used to them for a long time. They are not implemented in Gnome Shell, and nobody has bothered implementing them. Even more, menu mnemonics apparently are [not supported](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2448) in Gnome Shell.

Ubuntu: [Bug report at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1710421)

Gnome: [Upstream bug report at former bugzilla site](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733297)

Gnome: [Currrent issue on gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/914)

Answer (score 0):

I've now found that super-up and super-down does maximize and unmaximize on the windows. This works on ubuntu 16, 18 and 20 at least and includes terminal windows also. Super being the button between ctrl and alt with the windows logo on most keyboards I've ever seen.