# Keyboard shortcut for application menu dropdown

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, top-bar

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the dropdown list that is at the top of the screen just next to "activities"?  In the image is an example of the menu I mean when google chrome is the active program.

The reason I'm asking is that some programs don't like Ctrl+Shift+Q to close them, well basically chrome doesn't and it annoys me.  It would be handy to have a quick way to access this menu then quit the program.  I know there is Alt + F + x then enter for chrome but that might differ between programs whereas quit is pretty much always an option in this dropdown.

Using only the keyboard I would like to open this menu then navigate using the up and down keys to the desired item.

I am on 20.04

[image]

Comment: Left Windows key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use window menu accelerators/mnemonics in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032810/how-to-use-window-menu-accelerators-mnemonics-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard Ubuntu Desktop (Gnome Shell), try <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the Application menu.