# Minimize window keyboard shortcut... impossible?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Can it be true that Ubuntu 21 / Gnome, not only has no minimise window shortcut key, but it isn't even possible to set one? The keyboard shortcuts settings panel has shortcuts for zillions of obscure functions, but nothing for that most fundamental of functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use window menu accelerators/mnemonics in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032810/how-to-use-window-menu-accelerators-mnemonics-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: @N0rbert Not a relevant duplicate. Current question is on a shortcut key to minimize, not on accessing the window menu.

Comment: Name has changed: The shortcut your are looking for in "Settings" is "Hide window".

Answer (score 11):

Try <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (`H` standing for "hide").

There are [lots of keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-nav.html.en) to navigate the UI without a pesky mouse or touchpad getting in the way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my system (20.04 LTS), Super+H just tries to insert a `h` character. The other combinations, such as Super+arrow left (maximize vertically along the left side of the screen) do work as expected.

Comment: thanks, seems to work for me on Ubuntu 21. Hopefully someone will change the Gnome menu to "Hide" for consistency.... though I don't see why they had to reinvent its name.

Comment: `Super + H` does work correctly on 20.04.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have a minimize window in Ubuntu 18 either.  Perhaps you mean "Hide window" for which the default mapping is Super-H.   However, the button in the toolbar is still called minimize.